# Row level average calculation tableau

Tags: average, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I need to calculate average in tableau..one equation was sum(var A* varB)/sum(varB)..I have converted it into row level equation as avg((varA*varB)/varB) and it is working fine.but now I have another equation i.e sum(varA*varB)/total(sum(varB)).could some one help me how to convert this into row level average calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic scenario where you can leverage **Level of Detail** expressions in Tableau

read here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm

Your expressions would emerge like : `AVG([{FIXED [Segment]], [Category]] : SUM([Sales]])}])`

You will have greater control over row-level operations using LoD

Please read the link and try it